# HTML5 SVG: Calculating text size for dynamically created SVG content

Tags: javascript, html, svg

My code currently adds content to pre-existing SVG element. In order to calculate the size of an element that will sit behind the text, the size of the text that is added below needs to be known. However the dimensions of the element are not available immediately after the add (see below):

```
var svgNode; // supplied earlier in the code
var svgNs = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

var textNode = document.createElementNS(this.svgNs,"text");
textNode.setAttributeNS(null,'x','0');
textNode.setAttributeNS(null,'y','0');  
textNode.setAttributeNS(null,'class','node-text');

svgNode.appendChild(textNode);
```

I was hoping for an event in lieu of the information being available, something like:

```
textNode.addEventListener("onrender", onNodeTextEvent); // Yeah, this event does not appear to exist. Got it.
```

Answer (score 0):

As I don't think this question has been asked in this manner, I thought I'd leave it presented in this way. Turns out that (at least on Firefox) the bounding box is valid after the element is added to the 'svg' element (which is already part of the document tree).

```
svgNode.appendChild(textNode);
var bbox = textNode.getBBox();
// ... Work with bbox
```

Answer sourced from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27626991/6154987